# RStudio window larger than laptop screen

Tags: rstudio

When I open RStudio, the screen comprising the 4 window panes is larger than my laptop screen (13'' MacBook Pro), causing me to have to toggle left and right.

I believe this stems from playing with the zoom options under View and Zoom Console under View > Panes. I think the solution is to reset everything back to RStudio's default pane setting.

Is there a way to unzoom panes in RStudio. I haven't found any help on the RStudio support pages.

Answer (score 0):

Which zoom factor is defined inside Tools/Global Options/Appearance?
[How to access the zoom factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vff2T.png)